# pass filename as variable to jQuery script

Tags: php, jquery

I want to pass a filename to a jQuery script. The complete path is set as a variable in a php file called $filerurl. jQuery should open the file, using the path and filename in that variable, but it is not working at all. Is there something wrong with using  url: "", or is the variable not being passed to the script for some reason?

If I hardcode the filename into the jQuery script it works.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
 "use strict";
 jQuery.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "<?php echo $fileurl?>",
    dataType: "text",
    success: function(data) {processData(data);}
  });
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: This _will_ work _if_ you create that javascript in a dynamic manner using php. This will _not_ work if you use a static javascript file you reference, since in that case there is no php environment that could provide the value.

Comment: You must write this script in your PHP file, not in your JS file.

Comment: However the better approach here is to code that value in the html markup you generate by php, maybe in a hidden input or some attribute value. You can then "read" that value by means of javascript and use it. That allows to use a static javascript file which has benefits like portability and efficiency.

Comment: Thanks. How can I "read" the value by means of javascript? It would be a lot more efficient for me to keep this script in a separate file

Comment: The filename is actually based on the url, it is created using basename(getcwd()); and appending that to the filepath. is it possible to put that inside of the jQuery script somehow?

Comment: XY Problem, just use `url: "",`

Comment: That will return the entire url though, I just want the last folder name, For example:
http:/www.mysite.com/s/foo/index.php -> basename(getcwd()) returns "foo"

Comment: Is it possible to put the basename function inside of jQuery, something like this: (this does not work as is, but works inside of php file)
 url: "<?php echo 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/csvbucket/articles/articles' . basename(getcwd()) . '.csv'; ?>",